# How to customise devise views in rails 3.2 to include only some elements in the sign up form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am a rails newbie and I have started hacking together a web app.

I used devise to set up user registrations and also generated the devise views templates.

I added custom models in there - username, first name, surname etc. I then added them in the attr_accessor in user.rb etc. and validates for the presence of these details

I thought of adding these elements in the edit registration form which worked successfully.

On the signup page - the code asks only for email, password, confirm password (as is set as default by devise).

If i now try and register as a new user (after all these steps), i get an error saying that First name cannot be empty, surname cannot be empty etc.

How can i exclude these from the sign up yet keep them active in the user profile edit?

I hope I'm making sense.thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, during signup/registration you want to only ask for email and password, excluding the other User model attributes (first name, surname) from that form.  However you also want to later have these other attributes validated when the user edits their profile.

So since you are validating for the presence of these extra attributes which are not provided when the signup form is submitted, the attempt to create a new user record simply fails to create at validation.

Try the **`:on => :update`** validation option to specify that certain fields should only be validated when later updated, rather than the default which is to validate any time a record is saved.  Like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :email, :presence => true
    validates :firstname, :presence => true, :on => :update
    validates :surname, :presence => true, :on => :update
    ...
end
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#on

Comment: Thank you so much. That's the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

you can go into your views > devise folder and create a registrations folder if its not there and make a new.html.erb
have a look at the file that you find under the link:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb

copy it to your new file and customize it as you want... it should overwrite the devise default view.